# SSL redirect/rewriting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, ssl

I have an issue that cannot seem to find an answer for so hoping someone can assist.

I have a dynamic website that has 300+ unique domains pointing to it.

Recently needing the secure this with an SSL I need to use a UCC/SAN certificate. I only want to put the www version of each domain on the certificate to save money and space on the certificate (seems Safari only allows for 318 entries per cert).

Question I have is how do you redirect traffic to www. so it matches the certificate if the requested URL begins with https.

Example: I am using http to https and adding www prefix using URL Rewrite for IIS

```
"http://www.example.com" goes to "https://www.example.com"
"http://example.com" goes to "https://www.example.com"
"https://example.com" fails because of certificate name mismatch
```

I apologize for my ignorance but it seems like the browser verifies the certificate before allowing the redirect to happen? Is there a method I am unaware of?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

As you note, you can do most of this with the IIS URL Rewrite module.

The following rule can be added to your `web.config`

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
       <rule name="RedirectToSecure" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\..*$" negate="true"/>
         <conditions >
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

This rule has a match that captures everything on the path of the URL, it then has two conditions, the first checks that the request wasn't on HTTPS, the second checks to see if the host includes `www.`, both of these have match to trigger the rule, finally the action will permanently redirect the user to the secure, www version of the requested URL.

You could then have another copy of this rule with just the first condition to redirect the non-SSL version of the www domains to HTTPS (just remove the `www.` part from the action as well).

However you are slight hampered by not including certificates for the non-`www` versions. Browsers do indeed confirm that the certificates sent by the server for a request match the requested host, and will throw warnings and errors up to the user if they don't. Without a certificate that covers the non-`www` versions there's not really any way around this.

Obviously SAN certificates are probably a cheaper option than 300+ wildcards, however another option to consider, depending on your hosting solution, would be automating Let's Encrypt certificates instead - this would allow you to generate and install certificates for the root and www subdomain as required. This would have to be automated however as these certificates expire after 3 months, and generating them for 300+ domains would be very labour intensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reverse proxy to achieve this.

From the `IIS` home page, select or double click the site. On the right sidebar called Actions, click Bindings. Add a binding for `https`. Set the hostname to `example.com`. You'll have to select an SSL certificate for it. Also specify a physical path. Let the path be a new folder on your path, lets call `f1`.

[image]

After that, the next step to is to redirect traffic going to `http://example.com` to instead go to `http://www.example.com`. You'll use the URL Rewrite module to do so.

From the website's homepage select `URL Rewrite`. The `URL Rewrite` page shows up. From the right sidebar select `Add Rule`, then select `Reverse Proxy`. Specify the Inbound rule as: `https://www.example.com`. Uncheck `Enable SSL Offloading`.

[image]

Click OK, you'll be taken back to the rules. Double click the newly created inbound rule. The `Edit Inbound Rule` page shows up. In the section of `Conditions`, remove the `{CACHE_URL}` entry from the list. Go down to the Rewrite URL edit box and modify the value to be: `https://www.example.com/{R:1}`

[image]

From the right sidebar click `Apply`. That should be enough to configure the URL rewrite.

Now from the left sidebar click `Application Pools`, select the relevant pool and change its `Identity` to `LocalSystem`.

Go to the folder you created, in this case `f1`. Under its properties, add a user called `IUSR`. The user is located on the local computer so if the computer name is `JUNIT` select `JUNIT` as the location.

You can now test the configuration. Let me know how it goes.